# What is the difference between .iloc[0:1] and .iloc[0] in Pandas? Is 1 Exclusive or Inclusive?

Tags: python

When I execute some function with `df.iloc[0:1]` it shows...
`Expected first_row to have type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> but had type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

But same function, with `df.iloc[0]` it gives me the output in series...
Please give me a explanation. Why two different outcomes?

Comment: `.iloc[a:b]` syntax is used to slice a sub-table from a table, thus it returns DataFrames. In your case it will be a data frame with only 1 series within. `.iloc[a]` syntax returns Series

Comment: The documentation shows clear examples that a single value returns a series, and a slice or list indexes will return a df

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my simple doubt @AlexeyLarionov and Chris